# Mongoose Schema not Casting in Object's Built-in Getter as Expected

Tags: mongoose

I just came across an unexpected mongoose behavior and want to confirm with those who are familiar with mongoose.

I understood the [mongoose guide on schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) to mean that it automatically casts to specified data types **whenever you reference the schema's property**.  The language used in the guide is fairly general and possibly ambiguous:

> Each key in our code blogSchema defines a property in our documents
>   which will be cast to its associated SchemaType. For example, we've
>   defined a property title which will be cast to the String SchemaType
>   and property date which will be cast to a Date SchemaType.

From my recent discovery, it doesn't seem it casts as generally as I thought.

I have a schema for `transaction` containing an `amount`, like so:

```
let transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    ...

    amount: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
```

From my client-side, my HTML submits the inputs to the router, and req.body parameters are assigned, like so:

```
router.post('/save', function(req, res) {

    let theTransaction = {
        _id: req.body.transactionId,

        ...

        amount: req.body.amount,
        description: req.body.description,
```

As I understand the process, HTML is sending a string back to the router, and so `req.body.amount` is actually a string.  I allow mongoose to save it, and there is no problem as far as the saved version goes.

**However,** let's say `theTransaction.amount` = 500.  When I refer to the `theTransaction` object I am saving, I see that 555 + theTransaction.amount = 555500.00, instead of 1055.

Here is my testing:

```
console.log("transaction.amount");       \\transaction.amount
console.log(transaction.amount);         \\500.00
console.log(typeof transaction.amount);  \\string
let nmbr = 555;
nmbr += transaction.amount;
console.log("nmbr");                      \\nmbr
console.log(nmbr);                        \\555500.00
console.log(typeof nmbr);                 \\string
```

I was surprised to see this.  I assumed that mongoose would have performed a cast in its built-in getter for the schema.  I started looking and found that you can [create your own getters in a mongoose schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-get).

I can appreciate the purpose of special-purpose getters like those shown in the mongoose documentation examples.  However, I can't see why mongoose would be designed to require me to create a getter for every basic type I create.

Am I misusing mongoose, or will I have to add a slew of getters to my schemas?  Or is there some other way I should deal with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell if you are creating the document correctly without seeing the code for it so I can't assist you with your issue directly. However I can verify that casting works perfectly in Mongoose.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const toySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  cost: { type: Number }
});

const Toy = mongoose.model('Toy', toySchema);

const toy = new Toy({
  name: 'Blaster',
  cost: '10.00'
});

assert.equal(typeof toy.cost, 'number'); // Passes
assert.strictEqual(toy.cost, 10.00); // Passes
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I am glad to know that.  You helped me expose the issue.  I did not use a new schema object when I created `theTransaction`.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Glad to hear it helped!